# Derivative of a functional and taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion, functional-calculus

In the book *Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur*, the authors used the derivation shown below:

[image: Derivation]

I have trouble understanding the step in equation 1.16. Shouldn't the term $\frac{dg(f')}{df'} $ replaced by $\frac{dg(f')}{dx} $. The authors used $\frac{dg(f)}{dx} $ in a similar derivation below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The confusion arises because of a printing error earlier in the book.

Relevant literature erratum:

> Page 13, line before eqn 1.13: the definition of $g‘$ should read $g‘=\mathrm{d}g/\mathrm{d}f$ (rather than $g‘=\mathrm{d}g/\mathrm{d}x$). (14/01/15)

https://tomlancaster.webspace.durham.ac.uk/qftgabook/errata/

Comment: I have undeleted this answer, as it appears that the question is related to a typographical error in the text.  This answer (1) gives a source for errata, and (2) quotes the relevant erratum.  This is a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that $g = g(f')$. To make it a bit clearer, call $\omega = f'(x)$, that means that

$$
g(\omega) = g(\omega_0) + (\omega - \omega_0)\left.\color{red}{\frac{{\rm d} g(\omega)}{{\rm d}\omega}}\right|_{\omega_0} + \cdots 
$$

That means that the linear term in the expansion is actually

$$
\color{red}{\frac{{\rm d} g(\omega)}{{\rm d}\omega}} = \frac{{\rm d} g(f')}{{\rm d}f'}
$$

Of course you use the chain rule and further expand it in terms of $x$